# Find the sum of the following series (manipulating it to a series)

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{\pi^{4n}}{n!}$$ I'm unsure how to approach this any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: $$(-1)^m\pi^{4m}=(-\pi^4)^m$$

Answer (score 3):

Try to combine like terms so it looks something like this
$$ \exp z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}
$$

> $z = -\pi^4$

Comment: I thought of doing this and i came across that i can simply factor the numerator to $$(\pi^4)^n$$ then that sum would simplify to $$e^{\pi/4}$$ but what happens to the $$(-1)^n$$

Comment: @Joemans The $-1$ merges into $\pi^4$. That is, $e^{-\pi^4}$.